# pgAdmin III SQL creating a point

Tags: postgresql, sql, pgadmin-3

I have created a table, dc_crimes, that has eight columns. I would like to fill the geom column with point data created from the lat and long column. The syntax I used to create the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE tmorr.dc_crimes
(
gid serial NOT NULL,
shift character varying(80),
method character varying(80),
offense character varying(80),
ward character varying(80),
latitude numeric,
longitude numeric,
geom geometry(Point,102285)
```

I then inserted data from a previous table. 
Syntax used:

```
INSERT INTO tmorr.dc_crimes (gid,shift,method,ward,latitude,longitude)
SELECT gid,shift,method,ward,latitude,longitude FROM tmorr.dc_crimes_v
```

This is where I am a bit lost. I tried to update the dc_crimes table and use the ST_MakePoint syntax to create points. Syntax used:

```
UPDATE tmorr.dc_crimes SET geom = ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude);
```

This returned an error:Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (102285)
SQL state: 22023

So I tried to set the geometry SRID using this syntax:

```
SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('dc_crimes','geom', 102285);
```

This also gave me an error: ERROR: column not found in geometry_columns table
CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function updategeometrysrid(character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying,integer) line 36 at RAISE
SQL statement "SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('','',$1,$2,$3)"
PL/pgSQL function updategeometrysrid(character varying,character varying,integer) line 5 at SQL statement

********** Error **********

ERROR: column not found in geometry_columns table
SQL state: P0001
Context: PL/pgSQL function updategeometrysrid(character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying,integer) line 36 at RAISE
SQL statement "SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('','',$1,$2,$3)"
PL/pgSQL function updategeometrysrid(character varying,character varying,integer) line 5 at SQL statement

I believe I need to put values in the ST_MakePoint() but I am not sure which points.

Comment: I'm surprised that PostGIS is not mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

I usually tackle this task as follow.

First create table without Geometry column

```
CREATE TABLE tmorr.dc_crimes
(
gid serial NOT NULL,
shift character varying(80),
method character varying(80),
offense character varying(80),
ward character varying(80),
latitude numeric,
longitude numeric )
```

Then I populate table with data

```
INSERT INTO tmorr.dc_crimes (gid,shift,method,ward,latitude,longitude)
SELECT gid,shift,method,ward,latitude,longitude FROM tmorr.dc_crimes_v
```

After that, I create a geom column by simply using

```
Alter table tmrr.dc_crimes Add column geom geometry;
```

Now, as Ajsymth has answered, you can run command like this.

```
UPDATE tmorr.dc_crimes 
SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 102285);
```

Comment: combining your feedback with the Ajsymth's feedback solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

UpdateGeometrySRID() is unnecessary because your column already has an SRID set, as indicated in your error message. You need to do something like this:

```
UPDATE tmorr.dc_crimes 
SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 102285);
```

(Assuming that 102285 is the actual SRID of your data).

Comment: combining your feedback with the below feedback solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

UpdateGeometrySRID triggers an exception when postgis is not in the search_path.
You can try this:

```
set search_path to your_schema, postgis_shema; -- replace with the correct schema names
SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('dc_crimes','geom', 102285);
```

In my case I installed postgis in public schema, but it could have been installed in postgis schema, so I do:

```
set search_path to my_schema, postgis, public;
```